# RedirectToAction() destroys string data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Inside my controller I have string variable

```
private string notificationMessage = "";
```

which I want to use to copy it's content to `ViewBag.Message` and display that content on the view.

So inside my edit action I populate it's (notificationMessage) content like this

```
notificationMessage = "data is succ. updated!";
return RedirectToAction();
```

But after redirection to Index action this string variable is empty;

How can solve this?

Comment: use TempData, tempdata keeps its value to second request as @boran's answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `RedirectToAction` returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser to make a **GET** request to the specified action. Since **HTTP is stateless**, you can't simply set something in one action and get it in another(when it is another GET request).

What you can do is

**1)** pass a querystring to your new action and check that in the next action method and show a message according to that.

```
return RedirectToAction("ThankYou","Account",new {msg="success"});
```

and in your ThankYou action

```
public ActionResult ThankYou(string msg)
{
  var vm=YourSuccessViewModel();
  if(msg="success") // you may do a null checking before accessing this value
  {
    vm.Message="Saved Successfully";
  }
  return View(vm);  
}
```

**2)** Store in a temporary place like Session / TempData. TempData is meant to be a very short-lived instance, and you should only use it during the current and the subsequent requests only!

```
TempData["UserMsg"] = "Saved Successfully";
return RedirectToAction("ThankYou","Account");
```

and in your `ThankYou` action you can read it and show to user as needed.

```
public ActionResult ThankYou(string msg)
{
   var msg = TempData["UserMsg"] as string; 
   //to do  : do what you want with the message and return the view.
}
```

Session object is the backing store for the TempData object, and it is destroyed more quickly than a regular session, i.e., immediately after the subsequent request.

Comment: great answer! how can I display TempData in the view? TempData["UserMsg"] ?

Answer (score 4):

Use `TempData` instead of `ViewBag`. It persists between requests.